# Looking for Outlook API that works in the same way as 'SearchREsults.item.select' for Office API or 'WordEditor' for VSTO

Tags: api, outlook-addin, add-in, office-js, outlook-restapi

I'm working on office Add-in for Outlook and need to select the text in the body of the message.

Here is the way how it's can be done with

1. word/excel Office API -`searchResults.items[0].select('Select')`
2. VSTO -`mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application()`

Could you please advice the way to implement the same functionality, but using Outlook API or any other way that can be used in Outlook office  add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use item.getSelectedDataAsync API. The link is below

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.6/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook

Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: 'getSelected' provides you already selected (highlighted) part of the text, and 'Set' is changing selected part of the text. 'SerchResult.item. select' is working in the other way - it searches for a specific part of text and selects and focus on it if text is at the bottom (scrolled down to the selected part). Could you please advice?

Comment: Ah ok, there is no API today in outlook that let's you do this. But as workaround you can do the following. 1) use getBody to get the body in HTML. 2) Use a string library to find the text. 3) Append the text with a stylesheet that highlights the text. 4) Use setBody to set the body back in the email. Hope this helps.

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT, Your help is appreciated, but the proposed scenario doesn't cover the whole functionality I need. I have a js script that can do the action. Could you please advise if I can run the script in the body? Here is a piece of code I'd like to use: document.body.createTextRange(); rng.moveToElementText(target); rng.select();

Comment: Hi Sam, unfortunately no, there is no way to do that with the web platform.